# Redirect user to page in a different ASP.NET Core Razor web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Razor app with two menu items that are active prior to login. I want to transfer (redirect?) to a different web site when either of the menu items is clicked. I've tried a Redirect, as shown below, but the current url is added to the string I specify.

```
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        string url = "www.google.com";

        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: By prepending the scheme, e.g. `https://`.

Comment: Yes, you cannot do a redirect to a different domain without a *full* URI, which includes the protocol/scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't take long to get the answer that was right in front of me anyway. Thanks to CodeCaster and Chris Pratt. Using a fully-qualified URL does work correctly.

```
        public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        string url = "https://www.google.com";

        return Redirect(url);
    }
```