# ASP.NET Razor Pages submit button does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I have this view:

```
@page
@model TreesOnMars.Pages.NewGameModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New Game";
}

<h2>New Game</h2>

<form method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label asp-for="Name"></label></td>
            <td><input type="text" asp-for="Name" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<button type="submit" asp-route-data="@Model.Name">Create Game</button>
```

With this page model:

```
[Authorize]
public class NewGameModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        Redirect($"Game/{Name}");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the game to create.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

But when I click the submit button, nothing happens - neither the OnGet nor OnPost methods get called. What's going on here? How can I make the submit button call OnPost()?

Comment: Since the context of your question has changed. I would advice you to change the question itself so it’s not misleading.

Comment: Please provide Controller method code.

Comment: The original question is answered by my answer, and there is no controller - this is Razor Pages.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, only got it working once I added the returnUrl parameter, no idea why though:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            ....
            }
        }

<form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Oops, I'm an idiot - the submit button needs to be *inside* the form!

Comment: However even though the `OnPost` method gets called, the redirect isn't working... I also tried `RedirectToPage("Game", Name);`...

Comment: Oh this question helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875794/redirect-user-to-page-in-a-different-asp-net-core-razor-web-site

Comment: So you added a `return` statement and changed the `OnPost` method to return an `IActionResult` instead of `void`?

Comment: Yep! That's what I did.